# Unexpected Dynamics for Vehicles

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using Hydro on Gazebo 1.9. I have made a utility vehicle model that is based off of the DRC Vehicle (using the DRC Vehicle/Vehicle ROS plugins). I am currently trying to match the dynamics of the model as closely as possible to the actual, real vehicle that I have. I get the Gazebo vehicle to move by applying a command rotational velocity to the back wheels through gazebo_msgs::LinkState /gazebo/set_link_state. The thing that is strange to me is that whether I give a small or large command velocity, it always takes approximately 2 seconds for the settling time to reach the command velocity. This means that if I give a small command velocity, the acceleration is small and if I give a large command velocity, the acceleration is large. I would think that the vehicle would take more time to reach a higher command velocity - is there any way I can make this more realistic? I've tried different types of vehicles and this behavior is consistent. I've also thought about giving command velocity as steps but since it always take 2 seconds to get to the command velocity, I wouldn't be able to get to a desired total time of like 3 seconds, only multiples of 2.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide!

*EDIT: my drive node*

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "toro_gazebo_drive_pub");

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher publ = n.advertise<gazebo_msgs::LinkState>("/gazebo/set_link_state", 1000);
  ros::Publisher publ2 = n.advertise<gazebo_msgs::LinkState>("/gazebo/set_link_state", 1000);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(20);

  while(ros::ok())
  {
  gazebo_msgs::LinkState msg; //gazebo_msgs::ApplyJointEffortTEST
  gazebo_msgs::LinkState msg2; //for second back wheel
  double mpers = 0.5; // m/s of vehicle
  
  msg.link_name = "drc_vehicle_xp900::toro::rear_left_wheel"; //  husky::back_left_wheel
  msg.pose.position.x = 0.0; // don't edit position.x though angular.x
  msg.pose.position.y = 0.0;
  msg.pose.position.z = 0.0;
  msg.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
  msg.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
  msg.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
  msg.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
  msg.twist.linear.x = 0.0;
  msg.twist.linear.y = 0.0;
  msg.twist.linear.z = 0.0;
  msg.twist.angular.x = 0.0;
  msg.twist.angular.y = 2.3875*mpers*10; // can modify this to move (+ = forward, - = backward), 2.3875 is for .1m/s
  msg.twist.angular.z = 0.0;
  msg.reference_frame = "drc_vehicle_xp900::toro::rear_left_wheel"; //  husky::back_left_wheel

  msg2.link_name = "drc_vehicle_xp900::toro::rear_right_wheel"; //  husky::back_right_wheel
  msg2.pose.position.x = 0.0; // don't edit position.x though angular.x
  msg2.pose.position.y = 0.0;
  msg2.pose.position.z = 0.0;
  msg2.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
  msg2.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
  msg2.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
  msg2.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
  msg2.twist.linear.x = 0.0;
  msg2.twist.linear.y = 0.0;
  msg2.twist.linear.z = 0.0;
  msg2.twist.angular.x = 0.0;
  msg2.twist.angular.y = 2.3875*mpers*10; // can modify this to move (+ = forward, - = backward)
  msg2.twist.angular.z = 0.0;
  msg2.reference_frame = "drc_vehicle_xp900::toro::rear_right_wheel"; //  husky::back_right_wheel

  publ.publish(msg);
  publ2.publish(msg2);

  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending back-wheel drive command:" << " wheels spinning at " << msg.twist.angular.y << " rad/s" << std::endl);//" rotation(z, steer) = " << msg.twist.angular.z << std::endl);

  ros::spinOnce();

  loop_rate.sleep();


  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7708/unexpected-dynamics-for-vehicles/) by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-12-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-12-18**:
Is there any rhyme or reason as to how questions get answered in this forum? Like for my question, did I 1) write a confusing question? 2) ask a question that no one knows the answer to? 3) ask a dumb question? 4) just not wait long enough for a response?

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-12-18**:
The reason I ask this is because I've tried a number of different ways and spent a lot of time trying to adjust my model/world and if I can't get this to work then I need to drop the Gazebo side of my project.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2014-12-18**:
are you setting joint velocity or applying effort at joint to achieve a velocity?

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-12-18**:
I'm setting a link velocity through the topic, gazebo_msgs::LinkState, to the two rear wheel links. I was trying to use gazebo_ros in a way that only used topic/msgs without any services/srvs. I've edited my post so that I show the node that I use to drive the vehicle.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2014-12-18**:
setting joint [link] velocity bypasses dynamics, so resulting behavior will not obey newton's second law. To make use of physics and dynamics properly, I recommend creating a PID controller to set joint effort commands and use joint velocity as feedback.  One approach I might take is by writing a model plugin (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin) to do this.

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-12-18**:
Ohhh, ok, I didn't know that that bypasses dynamics. For the model plugin method, do you have an example of giving a joint effort w/ or w/o PID control? I know that tutorial link applies a linear velocity and not an effort.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2014-12-18**:
Well, set velocity with ODE uses a linear motor, and the effect is that the solver finds a *sufficient force* to achieve velocity requested, so not exactly real-world like.

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-12-18**:
Ok, so I think I'm a bit confused. Should I be setting velocity using 'this->model->SetLinearVel' to get to my command velocity in a plugin, or is there a different set command for setting effort that I should use instead? Is there some reference/wiki where I can learn about the code to use for plugins (I found the bitbucket page for gazebo plugin examples but those don't have a lot of motion other than model_push)? And then, how can I get ROS to communicate with the Gazebo plugin to give...

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-12-18**:
...a command velocity or effort? I know that there is the 'Using Gazebo plugins with ROS' wiki page but that only deals with sensor plugins and skid steer/differential drive. (I am using SDF for my model and not URDF).

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2014-12-18**:
To guarantee that an effort is applied on every simulation step, ModelPlugin approach is preferred.  Use Joint::SetForce call (https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/6592c20d6b458911b17c2797364fec6b8365d199/gazebo/physics/Joint.hh?at=gazebo_1.9#cl-267) to apply joint efforts. I don't have a simple example handy at the moment, maybe someone else watching this thread does?  Another alternative is to to use ros_control (http://wiki.gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo)

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-12-19**:
Thanks, I will try Joint::SetForce. As for the ros_control, can transmission elements be used in an SDF too? I thought that it could only be done on a URDF.

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2015-02-04**:
I have a plugin with Joint::SetForce working when I start Gazebo by typing Gazebo but I instead get a "process has died" exit code 139 error when launching through ROS (roslaunch). For some reason the SetForce is the source of the issue. Roslaunch works if I just have 'this->model->GetJoint("rear_left_wheel_joint");'   but if I have 'this->model->GetJoint("rear_left_wheel_joint")->SetForce(1,5.0); I get the error. Any ideas as to why?

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2015-02-04**:
I realized what the issue was - I had everything correct except I had a model within a model so my line should have read: this->model->GetJoint("toro::rearleftwheeljoint")->SetForce(1,5.0);   where 'toro::' comes before my joint name. Marking this thread as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Follow the comments to see the progression that Hsu helped me get through to the solution.

---

Originally posted by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) with karma: 104 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0